# Are there forcing notions adding $\kappa$ random, sacks, prikry, or Mathias reals?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

This is my first question here, so if I am doing things incorrectly, please let me know. Now on to the question:

The forcing notion $Fn(\kappa,2)$, which constists of partial functions from $\kappa$ to $2$ with finite support, ordered by reverse inclusion, is known to add $\kappa$ new cohen reals.

Are there similare forcing notions adding $\kappa$ new random, sacks, prikry, or Mathias reals?

Comment: Misread this at first as to asking about such forcings for cardinal $\kappa$, instead of adding $\kappa$ many reals.

Comment: "Notion", rather than "notation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason $Fn(\kappa,2)$ works for adding $\kappa$ new cohen reals is, because there exists a bijection between $\kappa$ and $\kappa\times\omega$, therefore the forcing $Fn(\kappa,2)$ is isomorphic (as a partial order) to $Fn(\kappa\times\omega,2)$ which itself is isomorphic to a Finite Support iteration of Length $\kappa$ of Cohen Forcing.

Similarly, for any forcing of your desired type (be it random, sacks, ... forcing), you could use a Finite Support iteration of length $\kappa$ to obtain your desired forcing. If you need an introduction to Forcing Iterations, Jechs book on Set Theory is a good start.

Comment: Why do we need to use iterations instead of products here?

Comment: A finite support iteration of non-ccc forcings, such as Mathias forcing or Sacks forcing,  will (after $\omega$ many steps) always collapse $\omega_1$.   This is usually an undesirable feature, and this is a reason why countable support iteration was invented.  (But CS iterations has its own problems...)

Comment: @NoahSchweber For example, if you take the product of two Mathias forcings, it will lose some of the interesting properties that a single Mathias forcing or a CS iteration of Mathias forcing has, such as the Laver property.  (The product of two dominating forcing notions, or of three unbounded forcing notions, will add a Cohen real.) - Also, both FS and CS products of infinitely many Mathias forcings will collapse $\aleph_1$.  - Of course there are other produts (e.g. mixed support)

Comment: @Goldstern Sure, it's better to do so, but with the product you still add $\kappa$-many reals which are whatever-generic over $V$.

Comment: In this case using FS Iterations also highlights the similarity, as $Fn(\kappa\times\omega,2)$ is simply an FS Iteration of $Fn(\omega,2)$ of Length $\kappa$.

Comment: In addition to products and the iterations already mentioned, random reals admit the option of forcing with the measure algebra of $2^\kappa$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the existence of a measure algebra on $2^{\kappa}$? As far as i know, there is currently no known way of constructing a (non-degenerate) measure on $2^{\kappa}$.

Comment: @HannesJakob Take the product measure induced from the uniform measure on $2$.

Comment: Of course, im sorry, i confounded $2^{\kappa}$ and $\kappa^{\kappa}$.